# Extract appointments from pst file without loop

Tags: .net, vb.net

I use Independentsoft.Pst to extract appointments from pst file but the problem is that a for loop is going over the entire appointments of the file, which is taking some time in very big files. Ill be very happy if someone could show me a way to do that with no loop or a way to convert the Independentsoft.Pst itemCollection to an array.

my code:

```
Public Function getAppointment(ByVal file As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim AppointmentDetails As New List(Of String)
    Dim App As New List(Of ItemCollection)
    Dim calendar As Folder
    Dim PSTfile = New PstFile(file)
    Dim delta As TimeSpan = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd - MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart
    Dim DelResult As Integer = delta.Duration.Days

    Using PSTfile
        calendar = PSTfile.MailboxRoot.GetFolder("calendar")
        If calendar IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim items As ItemCollection = calendar.GetItems()


            For m As Integer = 0 To items.Count - 1
                If TypeOf items(m) Is Appointment Then
                    Dim appointment As Appointment = DirectCast(items(m), Appointment)

                    AppointmentDetails.Add(appointment.Subject)
                    AppointmentDetails.Add(appointment.CreationTime)
                    AppointmentDetails.Add(appointment.CreationTime.Date)
                    AppointmentDetails.Add(appointment.Duration)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Using
    Return AppointmentDetails
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean finding an appointment based on some particular value of one of its properties.
Here's some code using PIA.

```
Private Shared Function GetAppointmentsFolder() As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim result As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing

    If OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.DefaultItemType = Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem Then
        result = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    End If

    If result Is Nothing Then
        result = OutlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
    End If
    Return result

End Function

Public Function GetAppointment(billingInfo as string) As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Dim appointmentsFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = GetAppointmentsFolder()
    'Try to find an existing appointment (Using Find() Locates and returns an Outlook item object that satisfies the given Filter..)
    Dim outlookAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = CType(appointmentsFolder.Items.Find("BillingInformation]=""" & pstrAppointmentId & """"), Outlook.AppointmentItem)

    Return outlookAppointmentItem

End Function
```

Comment: No, that's not what i meant. I Want to get my appointments but without having an "MS office" installed. I Want to do it through pst outlook file that's on some location like local, or Ethernet